# Why the output of printf("%d","") is 173 in c language?

Tags: c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("%d","");//printing output
    getch();
}
```

The output is 173 .I am not getting why the output is 173.

Comment: There is no space in an empty string.

Comment: You're not passing an `int` so why do you expect any kind of sensible value?

Comment: `""` is not space, this is empty string. ' ' is space character. Try `printf("%d", ' ')` , you will get output 32.

Comment: Could be anything. You're printing a random memory address as an integer. If you want to print the string, use `%s`, If you want the pointer, use `%p`.

Comment: Use `printf("%d", ' ');`.

Comment: output 173 woww I was expecting an address value far bigger than 173, this 3 digit number is a shocker to me.

Comment: @kkk -- you should expect nothing. Attempting to print an address with the wrong conversion specifier leads to undefined behavior, `""` is a string literal which indicates an array somewhere in static storage, and even if the correct specifier were used `%p` converts addresses to printable characters in an implementation-defined way.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're trying to print a string as decimal integer, which means the decimal you try to print is going to be the pointer to the string (actually a pointer to the array of characters) and not the string itself.  To use an individual character use single-quotes, not double-quotes.

To accomplish what you're actually trying to do, do this:

```
printf("%d", ' ');
```

Note there is an actual space between the two single-quotes.

The result will be 32, which is the decimal value for the ASCII Space character.

Comment: Let the code be same,so it is printing 173  why?

Comment: @Shyampandit what is your platform/compiler versions etc.? The `173` is _undefined behaviour_ (google that). But I must admit that I expected some larger number.

Comment: i am using Turbo c7.

Comment: @Shyampandit Is that a DOS compiler? That would explain everything.

Comment: Yes it is DOS compiler ,till now i am not getting why the output is 173.